# How to supply side effect for RxBinding.textChanges() and preserve it's functionality on client side?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-extension, rx-binding, extension-function

Suppose that i'm writing my own View class, that represents editable field and contains EditText **tv_input** inside:

```java
class EditTextIconItemView : LinearLayout {
   fun setInputText(text: String?) {
        with (tv_input) {
            setText(text)
            setCharsCount(text?.length ?: 0)
            setSelection(text?.length ?: 0)
        }
    }

    fun setCharsCount(count: Int) {
        tv_chars_count?.text = "$count/$MAX_LENGTH"
    }
}
```

I'd like to delegate **textChanges()** to that internal EditText tv_input, so i'm writing the following code in my custom **EditTextIconItemView**:

```java
fun EditTextIconItemView.textChanges() =
        tv_input.textChanges().doOnNext { setCharsCount(it.length) }
```

That works well, but now i want my client code to actually skip initial value, so in client code i have:

```java
val et = EditTextIconItemView()
et.textChanges().skipInitialValue().subscribe { ... }
```

This requires me to explicitly specify the return type in **EditTextIconItemView** for **textChanges()**:

```java
fun EditTextIconItemView.textChanges(): InitialValueObservable<CharSequence> = 
         tv_input.textChanges().doOnNext { setCharsCount(it.length) }
```

But this won't compile since **doOnNext** returns Observable which cannot be cast to **InitialValueObservable**.

But i actually don't want the client code to handle that side effect and set up chars count on that View, this is the responsibility of **EditTextIconItemView** itself. But i' like to still be able to tell, whether to skip initial value or not on client's side.

How could i make it work?

Thank You!